# Difficulty adding constraints in compact form

Tags: gurobi

[My LP model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeRHR.png)

I currently have this model that i'm trying to code using python and Gurobi. I know what the answer is supposed to be but I can't seem to get it right.

I have the following code for my objective and my constraints. Where did I go wrong?

```
profit = gp.quicksum((C[j]-T[i])* x[(i,j)] for i in S for j in F)
p.setObjective(profit, GRB.MAXIMIZE)

for j in F:
  p.addConstrs((gp.quicksum(x[(i,j)] for i in S) <= A[i] for i in S), 'availability')

for i in S:
  p.addConstrs((gp.quicksum(x[(i,j)] for j in F) <= D[j] for j in F), 'demand')

for j in F:
  p.addConstrs((gp.quicksum(O[i] * x[(i,j)] for i in S) - (N[j] * gp.quicksum(x[(i,j)] for i in S for j in F)) >= 0 for i in S), 'octane')

p.addConstrs((x[(i,j)] >= 0 for i in S for j in F),'non-negativity')
p.update()
```